# Creating a MPK file Equivalent/project template in QGIS from a project file for being the standard for various QGIS projects

Tags: qgis

Currently I have a project with some layer groups, which contains shapefiles (with value relations to other layers etc.) and also has some tables (that are necessary for the value relations). I want to create something like a MPK file/project template, that other users in my organization can use, so that the table/shapefiles relations are always used and that they cannot be separated by accident. This project/mpk file will be on a local LAN server we have (for example a V drive) but will be saved/copied locally to seperate for projects.

**I heard a Geopackage is the best solution for this so far, but are there any others?**

**Note: right now we are not thinking about using a Database server, just this option for now.**